# How to add several parameters with slash in wordpress post url?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I want to add several parameters with slash not by question mark in Wordpress Post URL. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to write the re-write rule in .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve by WordPress Standard. See below quick step and follow WordPress docx for specific functions/filters, if you get stuck.

You need to use `add_rewrite_rule` as per WordPress Standard to pass query string as a slash based URL

```
   add_rewrite_rule( 
      '^pageslug/([^/]+)([/]?)(.*)', 
      //!IMPORTANT! THIS MUST BE IN SINGLE QUOTES!:
      'index.php?pagename=pageslug&page_id=$matches[1]', 
      'top'
   );   
});
```

This filter is used to target the query string variable.

```
    add_filter('query_vars', function( $vars ){
        $vars[] = 'pagename'; 
        $vars[] = 'page_id'; 
        return $vars;
    });
```

Update permalink settings

This will be used to get the value in a specific page

```
get_query_var( 'page_id' )
```